# Enabling CSRF to TRUE in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, csrf

Just read that CodeIgniter 2.x has built-in CSRF protection. Now upon reading the documentation, I didn't found anything relating CSRF, just an option of setting it to `TRUE` in the `config.php` file then that's it. However, in my system I don't use this `form_helper` which automatically incorporates the CSRF protection of the CodeIgniter, instead I have the native `<form>` of HTML.

My concern is do I need to do anything to implement the CSRF of CodeIgniter, or just setting the option to `TRUE` is enough?

Comment: Any thoughts or articles to share for that amigo?

Comment: Codeigniter comes with source. You only need to read it, you have it on your disk already.

Comment: Of course, I can read the source. However, I am not that advance to understand why does CodeIgniter's CSRF known to be broken. I'm interested to learn more about that. To be guided, perhaps.

Comment: My fault I might have mixed that with XSS. However, looking into the source for CSRF will a) tell you how it works b) show what function you might need to use for your `<form>` approach. And don't fear to not be the best, reading helps. It's not that complicated to read the sourcecode. They even left comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable CRSF in Codeigniter all you need to do is:

1. Set the option to "TRUE" in the config file
2. All your forms **MUST** use the [form_open() helper function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html). This will automatically generate and include a 'hidden' CSRF token in your forms. Codeigniter will then automatically check this token on each form submission as part of the security funciton. If it detects a CSRF error, it will throw a 401 error automatically.

You dont need to do anything else.

edit: I just re-read that you do not use form_open(). It might be possible to manually insert the CSRF token into the forms yourself - but it would be more work than is required. Just convert all your forms to use form_open - and it will work seemlessly.

*(And yes - this is one of the few poorly documented features in CI - so I understand why you couldnt find the answer - it took me a while as well)*

Comment: Thanks for that, if it does return a 401, how can I manage that? Will that display a 401 page?